# WebApi method with OdataQueryOptions is not showing properly on swagger documentation

Tags: swagger, asp.net-core-webapi, swagger-editor

rest API project:
Using:
dotnet core 3.1, swashbuckle.AspNetCore 5.3.3.
Implement Odata using Non-Edm Approach.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllers(mvcOptions =>
            mvcOptions.EnableEndpointRouting = false).AddNewtonsoftJson();
        services.AddOData();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseMvc(routerBuilder =>
        {
            routerBuilder.EnableDependencyInjection();
           routerBuilder.Expand().Select().Count().OrderBy().Filter().MaxTop(100);
        });
    }
```

For Get operatoin,

```
    [HttpGet]
    [EnableQuery]
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(List<OutputDto>), 200)]
    [RequestHeaderMatchesMediaType("Accept", new[] { HttpMediaTypes })]        
    public async Task<IActionResult> Get(InputForGetDto input, ODataQueryOptions<OutputDto> options, [FromServices] IRepo<repository> _repository,
        [FromServices] IMapper _mapper)
```

In swagger documenation, this get operation cannot expand properly. the swagger documentation page got no reponse and dead for a long waiting time.
Find many unneccessary information in schemas part on swagger page:
[swagger schemas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/76v57.png)

How to make this operation showing correctly on swagger documenation?